# Woocommerce product options conditional

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a shoe product that have options( size, width, color ). Is there a way in woocommerce to change values of an option depending on what option is selected.

Ex. 
width = small, medium, large
size = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

if I select "small" sizes available will only be "1,2,3"
if I select "medium" sizes available will be "4,5"
and if "large" size will be "6" only

I want to try using javascript but I thought that it will be inefficient because not all sizes have the same values so I'm thinking this should be done in the wordpress backend so I can change it on every item. Here is a sample site that has the function that I mentioned -> http://www.shoesrx.com/munro-cookie.aspx#.VzsxamR96Rv ( notice that the size changes when a certain width is selected )

Any advice / suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You may need this cheap commercial plugin: [WooCommerce Extra Product Options](http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-extra-product-options/7908619)

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at the plugin, seems like a good one.

Comment: Yes is think it will do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a simpler way. What you need to do is create some attributes in the Products menu in Woocommerce by clicking Attributes in the bottom of the menu. Add a new attribute called Size and then click the cog icon on the right of the attribute table. From here you can add terms such as 1, 2 and 3. As the terms will be numbers you need to call the slug by its alphabetical name such as size-one, size-two.

Then when you view the product it should display the attributes dropdown allowing you to filter the results.

Comment: Yes this will do but you have to generate 100s of variations especially on products that has many options.

Comment: But yeah it got the job done.  

Thank you for sharing this!